# Using windows authentication in sharepoint 2013 configured for claims forms authentication

Tags: 2013, web-services

I am trying to access a SharePoint 2013 from axis2 webservice through a java application. The SharePoint 2013 is configured in both windows and claims authentication, now my code is like this

```
AuthenticationStub authenticationStub = new AuthenticationStub(sharepointContext.getSiteURL() + "/" + authenticationWSExt);
authenticationStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
                 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, authCtx);
authenticationStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
                 org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, "false");
List<org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header> headers = new ArrayList<org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header>();
        org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header header = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header();
        header.setName("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED");
        header.setValue("f");
        headers.add(header);
        authenticationStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_HEADERS, headers);
AuthenticationStub.Login login = new AuthenticationStub.Login();
login.setUsername(sharepointContext.getUserName());
login.setPassword(sharepointContext.getPassword());
logWriter.finer(methodName, "logged in as user name : " + sharepointContext.getUserName());
authenticationStub.login(login);
```

So I am saying to authenticate through windows classic mode, but still I am getting

> Site is not configured for claims forms authentication

Why is that? What did I miss? Should I set some other parameter? Or what should I change so that my authentication is successful?

Comment: Did you get a resolution for your issue?

Comment: No i didn't get the solution yet. Still stuck in the same problem. Can you give me any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still looking for a resolution here, this might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh124553(v=office.14).aspx